# Upload Picture to a SQL Server database using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, sql-server-2008, file-upload

I was looking to upload an image (jpg) to a SQL Server database using MVC.

Basically - my user would be able to navigate to a page, Browse their computer using a file upload textbox/browse button, and click submit to have the file uploaded to the database.

Fairly new to MVC and not quite sure how to go about this.

There's lots of tutorials on the web however many of them with negative comments.

Does anyone know of any tried and tested tutorials that I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually handle uploads with a model binder. I have a blog post [here](http://mattias-jakobsson.net/post/2009/11/19/Handling-image-uploads-with-AspNet-Mvc.aspx) where I describe how I do it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That domain isn't used anymore. I have updated the link now.